# How can I find all the three-digit numbers that each digit is in 3 and the addition of the digits is equal to the number itself

Tags: c#

How can I find all the three-digit numbers that each digit is in 3 and the addition of the digits is equal to the number itself.

for example:

```
3 ^ 3 + 7 ^ 3 + 1 ^ 3 = 371
```

**Update**

I have to find all the numbers from 100-999 and then, separate each digit and then perform a three-digit operation (mathematical operation) and check whether all digits are equal to the number itself

The number 371 fulfills the following condition: the sum of its digits in the third is equal to the number itself

Comment: I dont quite understand the question, can you be more specific, and include better examples for us dumb folk

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: I have to find all the numbers from 100-999 and then, separate each digit and then perform a three-digit operation (mathematical operation) and check whether all digits are equal to the number itself

Comment: The number 371 fulfills the following condition: the sum of its digits in the third is equal to the number itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer**

You could use something like this

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetDigits(int num)
{
   do { yield return num % 10; } while ((num /= 10) > 0);
}

public static bool SomeWeirdMathsOp(int num)
{
   return num == GetDigits(num).Sum(x => (int)Math.Pow(x, 3));
}
```

**Usage**

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(100, 900).Where(SomeWeirdMathsOp);
foreach (var item in list)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output**

```
153
370
371
407
```

[**Full demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yKRZMP)

---

## Benchmarks

Just for fun (and because i'm annoying) i decided to benchmark everyone's answers

**Results**

```
Mode            : Release
Test Framework  : .NET Framework 4.7.1
Benchmarks runs : 100 times (averaged/scale)

Scale : 900
Name      |     Time |    Range | StdDev |    Cycles | Pass
--------------------------------------------------------------
MineTimes | 0.136 ms | 0.016 ms |   0.03 |   456,359 | Yes
Mine      | 0.250 ms | 0.005 ms |   0.05 |   830,104 | Base
Mahsa     | 0.332 ms | 0.008 ms |   0.03 | 1,122,867 | Yes
JohnyL    | 2.135 ms | 0.204 ms |   0.34 | 7,262,956 | Yes
```

MineTimes is *Enigmativity's* version which just does the power manually

```
public static bool SomeWeirdMathsOp(int num)
{
   return num == GetDigits(num).Sum(x => x * x * x);
}
```

---

## Additional Resources

[yield (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)

> When you use the yield keyword in a statement, you indicate that the
>   method, operator, or get accessor in which it appears is an iterator.
>   Using yield to define an iterator removes the need for an explicit
>   extra class (the class that holds the state for an enumeration,

[% Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/remainder-operator)

> The remainder operator (%) computes the remainder after dividing its
>   first operand by its second. All numeric types have predefined
>   remainder operators.

[Enumerable.Sum Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Computes the sum of the sequence of Double values that are obtained by
>   invoking a transform function on each element of the input sequence.

[Math.Pow Method (Double, Double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns a specified number raised to the specified power.

[Enumerable.Range Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range.

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(100, 899)` should be `Enumerable.Range(100, 900)`.

Comment: @SirRufo `Enumerable.Range(100, 900)` will create a list of ints from 100-999

Comment: Remark to myself: Do not answer or comment before the first coffee :o)

Comment: Your code would run twice as fast if you replaced `(int)Math.Pow(x, 3)` with `x * x * x`.

Comment: @Enigmativity indeed you are correct, lets run test it

Comment: @Enigmativity twice as fast indeed!